# Securely storing user data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl, security

I'm creating a service that will gather user data such as username, name, email, login password. How do I securely store this data? One thing I was thinking is store it encrypted in the DB so that if anyone gets access to the DB they won't be able to use the data.

But that arises two issues - #1 - much much slower search of the DB and #2 the encryption key will still be stored in the Perl script that will encrypt the data submitted by the user so if someone gets access to the whole server they'll still be able to decrypt all data.

So I was wondering what do services such as Twitter, Facebook, Hotmail, etc. use to securely store data?

BTW: as I said I'm working with Perl/MySQL.

Thank you all nice people!

Comment: I suspect those services don't encrypt the data in the database... what they do do is try to prevent SQL injection.... you could also encrypt the hard drive. The only time you'd want this kind of security is for things like HIPAA and possibly need for credit card transaction processors and the like. as others have said use a 1 way salted hash for passwords.

Answer (score 2):

You should try and avoid encrypting everything in the database.  At the very least you will have to figure out which fields are being used for searching, relations, sorting etc and leave those unencrypted.  You have to consider layers of encryption based on who you are hiding the data from.  It would also help if you are clear about the differences between one way hashing (MD5, SHA), symmetric encryption and asymmetric encryption.

Encrypting passwords in the database makes sense because it hides the passwords from the dba or anyone with the ability to query the db directly.  Actually, passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed.  This way you can never recover a password, you can only generate a new one.

Data that needs to be recovered will be encrypted, so that it can be decrypted.  There are various algorithms for doing that and they have different attributes of strength and cost (in terms of processing time and memory). You should choose one which suits your purpose.

The thing here is that encryption and decryption need to be done in the application and not in the database.  The reason for this is that at some point there might be an open network between the database and the application servers and any data transmitted between the application and the database could be sniffed.

In deciding between symmetric and asymmetric encryption, there are two factors.  One is for how long does this information need to be kept secure.  If it is a bid on an auction that is going to end in 2 days, you may use symmetric encryption, because it ideally will not matter if people figure out things after that.  Credit card numbers typically do not have to be kept safe.  If you are storing the expiry date and the ccv numbers of the card then those have to be kept safe, typically for years.  In that case you have to use asymmetric encryption.

In encrypting the whole file system it is not the performance degradation that you have worry about mainly. As far as I have seen, it requires a person to key in the correct password when OS is booting, and that requires physical access, and persons who can be trusted to know the password staying as close to the servers as the SLA requires.  In this it is like setting a bios password or a grub password.  If you indeed encrypt your file system, make sure to verify this or find a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out that encryption will incur a slowdown. How much will depend on lots of different factors, so you'll need to benchmark your code.

But in reality the most important thing to protect is probably the password since if that is compromised then the users' accounts on other services could be compromised as well since people tend to reuse the same username/email/password combos.

Fortunately passwords are easy to secure. Use a 1-way hash like SHA1 with a salt (to protect against rainbox tables) and never store the actual password in your DB. Store the salted-hash. Then when the user logs in you can check the pw they give you against the hashed one to make sure it matches without ever having to store what their pw really is.

Comment: +1. I'm constantly shocked at how many people don't understand one-way encryption, and believe that it must be possible to decrypt stored data in order to compare it to input.

Comment: I would recommend stronger than sha1 now... for future security probably better to go with sha512 or blowfish

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250372/encryption-security-on-a-webapp/3250720#3250720).  The gist of it is that you can add security, but there is no 100% foolproof way to avoid a compromise of (some of) your user information if your web application is completely broken.

Encrypting the filesystem on which the database is stored minimizes many other types of vulnerabilities.  Encrypting data in the database protects you against those and also against a user breaking your DB password.  Encrypting data in the database with a hardware token provides the best protection but is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. You can encrypt the data in the middle tier

   - You can encrypt the database

You will encounter slower searches either way. In both cases, the encryption key is not included in the backup file set.